# Display HTML and accompanying script in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I am working on creating a dropdown select element to show plots using vue framework.

Below I have written a Vue component for accomplishing this task. (The code may not be efficient as I am new to javascript and vue).

When an option is selected I need to output a HTML element which contains a plotly plot.

1. If it is pure HTML without any scripts. I can output it using the v-html directive in a div to output the html.
2. However my plotly HTML also contains script to generate the plot (example:

   ```
   <div id=\"66c17317e1d\" style=\"width:100%;height:400px;\" class=\"plotly html-widget\"><\/div>
   <script type=\"application/json\" data-for=\"66c17317e1d\">{\"x\":{\"visdat\":{\"66c11ad580f2\":[\"function () \",\"plotlyVisDat\"]},\"cur_data\":\"66c11ad580f2\",\"attrs\":{\"66c11ad580f2\":{\"x\":[1,2,3,4,5,6,). ... </script>
   ```

   )
3. Researching on this topic, I understood that, because this script came after the DOM has been rendered it will not run anymore script. I understand running scripts like this will open security vulnerabilities. However, I am not doing any frontend or backend app development. I simply want to output this to a html and there is no user interaction except for selecting which plot to show from the dropdown list.
4. What is the process to display HTML containing a script in vue.js?

I am also open to better alternative ways to accomplish this task, as I am totally new to js and vue.

P.S. I just want to output a plot with HTML and script to generate a svg using a select/dropdown option. I would prefer a way to not render all the plots at the start as there are too many plots. I am trying to use HTML stored in JSON files to generate the plots (At least for now this is my naive solution to rendering HTML plots in a HTML document).

The component code is:

```
Vue.component('my-plot',{
              template:`
    <b-card no-body>
     <h1>Select box</h1>
    <b-dropdown text="Select Item" >
      <b-dropdown-item v-for="option in tabs"
                        :key="option"
                        :value="titles[option-1]"
                        @click="plotcontent = content[option-1]">
        {{titles[option-1]}}
      </b-dropdown-item>
    </b-dropdown>
     <div v-html= "plotcontent"> </div>
  </b-card>
    `,
    data: function () {
    return {
    tabs: [1,2,3,4,5],
    titles: ["a","b","c","d","e"],
    plotcontent: "<div>nothing here</div>",
    content: [
"<div id = "1"> </div> <script> plotlyscript</script>",
"<div id = "2"> </div> <script> plotlyscript</script>",
"<div id = "3"> </div> <script> plotlyscript</script>",
"<div id = "4"> </div> <script> plotlyscript</script>",
"<div id = "5"> </div> <script> plotlyscript</script>"],
    tabCounter: 5
    }
    },
    methods:{
      cprint: function(event){
    this.$nextTick(function () {
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
      })

      }
    }
})
```